# How can I use a custom adapter with the cwac-endless adapter?

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter, cwac-endless

I want to add the endless adapter functionality to my custom adapter. How can I use this combination? Thank you.

Comment: Just in case anyone gets here like I did, looking for a good example. I found this one http://droidista.blogspot.co.il/2011/04/using-cwacs-endlessadapter-with-custom.html - worked well!
You can replace the ArrayAdapter to BaseAdapter easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You follow the instructions in the [GitHub repo for the project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless).

`EndlessAdapter` is a wrapper around your custom adapter.

So, *first*, you get your custom adapter working correctly on its own. Then, you create your `EndlessAdapter` subclass (with your implementation of `cacheInBackground()`, etc.), wrap your custom adapter in an instance of your `EndlessAdapter` subclass, and put your instance of your `EndlessAdapter` subclass in your `ListView`.

The `demo`/ sub-project contains some sample activities. They *happen* to wrap an `ArrayAdapter`. They could just as easily wrap a `DineshSuperAwesomeAdapter`.